# reactjs: Tooltip hides in react-select component

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-select

I am using React-JS to work on a project and I need to use tooltips on a react-select element.

[image: 1]

As you can see in the picture above, the tooltip hides and cannot be fully visible.

I have tried solving this by adjusting the css code to include the z-index and the overflow options, like this:

```
.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted black; 
  overflow: visible !important;
  z-index: 101;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 320px;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -160px;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  opacity: 0.8;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px 0;
  border-radius: 6px;
  overflow: visible !important;
  z-index: 101;
 
  position: absolute;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible !important;
  overflow: visible ;
  z-index: 101;
}
```

Similarly, I have also adjusted the Select component, to set it to a lower zIndex:

```
<Select
              instanceId={obj._id}
              options={answers}
              onChange={(inputValue) =>
                handleAnswers(inputValue, quest[0])
              }
              defaultValue={ans[0]}
              loadingMessage={() => "Loading..."}
              noOptionsMessage={() => "No options"}
              placeholder="Choose your answer"
              isSearchable={false}
              styles={{
                zIndex: 100,
              }}
              isMulti
            />
```

No option has worked so far, what could solve the issue? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `position: fixed !important;` style did the job

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).